# remove some parts of a url in php echo

Tags: php, echo

How to remove some parts of url in php echo syntax
for this link

```
   http://www.celebrationinvites.com/retro_blocks_maroon_white_graduation_announcement_zazzle_invitation2-256439384662275012.html
```

this code

```
    <meta name="twitter:image" value="<?php echo(str_replace("367.jpg", "150.jpg", $imageSrc)) ?>" />
```

is rendering this

```
    <meta name="twitter:image"       
    value="https://rlv.zcache.com/retro_blocks_maroon_white_graduation_announcement-r86c000be19e542fa8a3430823ddc7146_6gdu5_150.jpg?rlvnet=1&amp;bg=0xFFFFFF" />
```

the **&** is being encoded to

```
     &amp;
```

any idea how to decode this part, so it is just an **&**. also completely remove everything after .jpg

just a beginner , so this is what i tried

```
    <meta name="twitter:image" value="<?php echo (substr($string, 0, -25, $imageSrc)) ?>" />
```

not working 
please help
Kind Regards
Maria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your  initial `echo`  and  `str_replace`  are not  encoding  `&`. It  is
already encoded in your `$imgSrc` variable. You can manipulate that with
the [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)  and [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) functions, but  I don't think
it  is needed  since  you're going  to remove  what's  after the  `.jpg`
anyway.

The  `substr` approach  is correct,  but you  misused the  function. The
first parameter is the string to be manipulated. You passed it as forth.
There is no forth argument, actually.

Also, `<?php echo  ... ?>` can be  reduced to `<?= .. ?>`.  So this will
work:

```
<meta ... value="<?= substr($imageSrc, 0, -25) ?>" />
```

If you don't know in advance where  the `.jpg` is, you can search for it
and use the resulting position as length for `substr`, plus an offset of
this needle length itself:

```
<meta ... value="<?= substr($imageSrc, 0, strpos($imageSrc, '.jpg')+4) ?>" />
```

Instead of [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)  there is also [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)  for the reversed
approach. And the regex options. Many options!

Comment: worked like a charm! thank you so much! 
so if i wanted to combine these two
<meta name="twitter:image" value="<?php echo(str_replace("367.jpg", "150.jpg", $imageSrc)) ?>" />
<meta ... value="<?= substr($imageSrc, 0, -25) ?>" />
so that the image is resized as well as the parts after.jpg removed...how do i go about that?

also in the solution above that you gave what does
+4) ?>" />
this part do? what does +4 actually ask the code to do? :) 
thanks again!

Comment: Hi @KeenLearner happy that it worked. About combining, you can nest the function calls. In place of the string in one of the function calls, use the other function. Something like `substr(str_replace("..."), 0, -25)`. Either that or do it in two steps somewhere else before in your PHP code, like saving the transformation to a new string and then again. If you need more detailed help please post another separated question and we will happily jump into it.

Comment: @KeenLearner regarding `+4`, as you know `substr` makes a sub string from the second parameter to the third. In this case 0 to what is returned by the function call. `strpos` returns the position of the searched string, but the position of the first caracter. So without the +4, it would cut the `.jpg` portion as well. Thus, it is just an offset, to add to the number returned by `strpos`. simple arithmetic

Comment: ok posted the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42539814/combine-two-functions-in-php-echo

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP function [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to split the input URL into components:

```
$pieces = parse_url("https://rlv.zcache.com/retro_blocks_maroon_white_graduation_announcement-r86c000be19e542fa8a3430823ddc7146_6gdu5_150.jpg?rlvnet=1&amp;bg=0xFFFFFF");
print_r($pieces);
```

This is the result:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => https
    [host] => rlv.zcache.com
    [path] => /retro_blocks_maroon_white_graduation_announcement-r86c000be19e542fa8a3430823ddc7146_6gdu5_150.jpg
    [query] => rlvnet=1&amp;bg=0xFFFFFF
)
```

Pick the component you need from the returned array, modify them and compose the new URL. To modify the path you can use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) (or other [string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)), [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) or [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

For example:

```
// Use regexp to make sure the string is replaced only at the end of the path
$path = preg_replace('/367\.jpg$/', '150.jpg', $pieces['path']);
```

Then put together only the pieces you need:

```
$url = $pieces['scheme'].'://'.$pieces['host'];
if ($pieces['port']) {
    $url .= ':'.$pieces['port'];
}
$url .= $path;
```