# combine two functions in php echo

Tags: php, function, echo

i need to combine these two functions

```
    <meta name="twitter:image" value="<?php echo(str_replace("367.jpg", "150.jpg", $imageSrc)) ?>" / 
    and
    <meta name="twitter:image"value="<?= substr($imageSrc, 0, strpos($imageSrc, '.jpg')+4) ?>" />
```

i have tried this

```
     <meta name="twitter:image" value="<?php echo(str_replace("367.jpg", "150.jpg", $imageSrc)),substr($imageSrc, 0, strpos($imageSrc, '.jpg')+4)?>" /
```

while the code has no issues but it renders this

```
     <meta name="twitter:image" value="https://rlv.zcache.com/seal_of_success_blue_graduation_announcement-r6c3587ec36fd4246afd2add46333186a_6gdu5_150.jpg?rlvnet=1&amp;bg=0xFFFFFFhttps://rlv.zcache.com/seal_of_success_blue_graduation_announcement-r6c3587ec36fd4246afd2add46333186a_6gdu5_367.jpg" /
```

whereas i want it to return just one url this

```
    https://rlv.zcache.com/seal_of_success_blue_graduation_announcement-r6c3587ec36fd4246afd2add46333186a_6gdu5_150.jpg
```

that  is replace 367.jpg to 150.jpg and remove everything after.jpg
 **?rlvnet=1&bg=0xFFFFFF**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call one function inside another and it will work:

```
<meta name="twitter:image" value="<?=
    str_replace(
        "367.jpg",
        "150.jpg",
        substr($imageSrc, 0, strpos($imageSrc, '.jpg')+4)
    )
?>" />
```

Or do it step-by-step saving to the variable:

```
# remove tail
$imageSrc = substr($imageSrc, 0, strpos($imageSrc, '.jpg')+4);
# replace size
$imageSrc = str_replace("367.jpg", "150.jpg", $imageSrc)

<meta name="twitter:image" value="<?= $imageSrc ?>" />
```

Comment: ok and if i want to add "rlvnet=1&view_padding=[285,0,285,0]" this after "?" instead of removing  everything after "?"

Comment: @KeenLearner if it is a fixed text, you can just add it after the closing `?>`, like `?>?rlvnet=....285,0]"`. Or add it to your string. In PHP you concatenate with the `.` operator. So for example, in the second example written in my answer you can add another line with `$imgSrc .= '?rlvnet...0]`;

Comment: and it works! finally after days and days of getting twitter cards to work with proper image resize! it is working! thank you so much!

Comment: I'm happy that it now works @KeenLearner ! The solution by Mathieu Bour below also has a nice usage of the `strstr` function to make it shorter

Answer (score 4):

Well, try

For example, I'll take `$imageSrc = "http://example.com/img_367.jpg?something"`

To be clear, you want first of all remove everything after the ?, an then replace 367 by 150. So try this :

```
<?= str_replace("367", "150", strstr($imageSrc, "?", true)) ?>
```

Comment: this has code error

after editing in php code validator..
it be should be this

<meta name="twitter:image" value="<?=(str_replace("367", "150", strstr($imageSrc, "?", true))); ?> and it is working as well! :)

Comment: Absolutely, my bad, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

`<?php echo str_replace('_367.jpg','_150.jpg',current(explode("?",$imageSrc))); ?>`